# How to set .bashrc to default to mounted directory when I SSH in

Tags: vagrant

This is a stripped down version of my VagrantFile.  At the end it, I was attempting to add a:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "\"\ncd /vagrant\" >> ~/.bashrc"
```

However I kept running into an issue where since `/vagrant` is a mounted directory it was saying "/vagrant does not exist" when I ran `vagrant up`.  **How can I set my default directory to be the directory where my site is mounted?**

**VagrantFile**

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = mydev-box"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.17.8.153"
  config.vm.hostname = "myhost.dev"

  # bootstrap
  config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl software-properties-common"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"

  # Update required settings.
  config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "echo \"127.0.0.1 myhost.dev\" >> /etc/hosts"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant/",mount_options: ["dmode=777","fmode=777"]

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one of the issue is that the command (even if working) will be done for root user.
You could pass `privileged: false` to make sure it is run as vagrant user. You could also specify the full folder to make sure the correct file is updated `/home/vagrant/.bashrc`

Second, vagrant seems to do string interpolation when using the `"` but not  when using `'`'

To make it work, I did the following

```
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "echo 'cd /vagrant' >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc"
```